# NHibernate ClassMap<T> code not executing

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, structuremap

I'm setting up a new project and have gotten NHibernate to work with structuremap...sorta. I'm using the NHibernate.Mapping.ByCode.Conformist setup with ClassMaps. No errors occur, but when I query over a session and there are records present in the database for a particular type, nothing comes back. Upon further examination, it appears that the mappings that I've set up for these types are not executing. Here's my code that wires up things for structuremap. I can confirm that it is being executed.

```
public class OrmRegistry : Registry
{
    public OrmRegistry()
    {
        var sessionFactory = BuildSessionFactory();
        For<ISessionFactory>().Singleton().Use(sessionFactory);
        For<ISession>().HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped().Use(s => sessionFactory.OpenSession());            

    }

    public ISessionFactory BuildSessionFactory()
    {
        var cfg = new Configuration().DataBaseIntegration(db =>
                                                              {
                                                                  db.ConnectionStringName = "LocalSqlServer";
                                                                  db.Dialect<MsSql2008Dialect>();
                                                                  db.Driver<SqlClientDriver>();
                                                                  db.KeywordsAutoImport = Hbm2DDLKeyWords.AutoQuote;
                                                                  db.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted;
                                                                  db.BatchSize = 500;
                                                              }).AddAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        if(HttpContext.Current != null)
        {
            cfg.CurrentSessionContext<WebSessionContext>();
        }
        else
        {
            cfg.CurrentSessionContext<ThreadStaticSessionContext>();
        }
        return cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
    }
}
```

I'm nearly certain I'm just missing something extremely obvious here, but I've been looking at it for a few hours and haven't had any success. I also got downsized a couple days ago, so I don't have a coworker around to look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you got your configuration initialized, but what about mapping? You need to initialize mappings like this (if you are using conventions):

```
var mapper = new ConventionModelMapper();

// TODO: define conventions here using mapper instance

// just an example on how I have been using it
var entities = ... // get all entity types here
cfg.AddDeserializedMapping(mapper.CompileMappingFor(entities), "MyMappings");

return cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
```

And another example if you are using mapping classes (from this [post](http://x-driven.blogspot.com/2011/12/nhibernate-mapping-by-code.html)):

```
var mapper = new ModelMapper();
var mappingTypes = typeof (InvoiceMapping).Assembly.GetExportedTypes()
    .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Mapping")).ToArray();
mapper.AddMappings(mappingTypes);

cfg.AddMapping(mapper.CompileMappingForAllExplicitlyAddedEntities());

return cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
```

Comment: Done in one. Nice. It's working perfectly now. Thanks for the help.